# PHP multiple If conditions are true

Tags: php

I have this PHP code:

```
$supplier = $line[2];
if ($supplier == "supplier")
{
} else {
Header("Location: premium.php");
}
```

Now I want that to include $supplier == "demo" to the PHP code to be as follows:

```
$supplier = $line[2];
if ($supplier == "supplier" && $supplier == "demo")
{
} else {
Header("Location: premium.php");
}
```

but the latter code is not working for either... I mean if the $supplier is equal to something else besides "supplier" or "demo" it is still bypassing it. It only worked for the first one.

How can I arrange it please?

Comment: Instead of the && you mean? thanks

Comment: && means and, a $supplier cant be 2 seperate things at the same time, try replacing && with || which means or

Comment: @PiedpiperMalta You better revisit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($supplier == "supplier" && $supplier == "demo")
```

can never be true, since the $supplier can never be both at same time. You need an OR there like so:

```
if ($supplier == "supplier" || $supplier == "demo")
```

Answer (score 2):

The line 
    `if ($supplier == "supplier" && $supplier == "demo")`

makes no sense. `$supplier` could not have changed in the middle of the conditional statement, thus that will never be true.  You might be looking for `||` (or).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely take this opportunity to understand the meaning of `&&` and `||` as others have mentioned, but if "or" is indeed the logic you're looking for, in this case I'd recommend this:

```
if ( in_array( $supplier, array( "supplier", "demo" ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

"&&" means: both connected statements have to be true !
"||" means: one of the statements have to be true !

Your construct doesn't make sense, because you said $supplier has to be "demo" AND "supplier", which can never be true, as a $var can only have one value.

WRONG:

```
if ($supplier == "supplier" && $supplier == "demo") // AND would also work
```

RIGHT:

```
if ($supplier == "supplier" || $supplier == "demo") // OR would also work
```